# Menu color change onclick

Tags: css, dotnetnuke

I have a menu almost similar to the ones in stackoverflow.com using DNN. How do I change the color of the selected menu?

I have managed to change the color while hovering (using CSS), but I am having trouble with this.

Can I achieve this effect of changing the color of a clicked item using only CSS?

Comment: Are you referring to having a menu item highlighted when on that page (as with stackoverflow's questions, tags, users, etc menu)? Or are these menu items all on one page and should remain highlighted without a page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

The A (anchor) tag has an :active state on click. You could try using it as a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an 'active' class to the current menu item. Depending on what cms you are using this may already be done. Then just style the active class for menu items accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what menu system you are using in your skin you may have two solutions:

1. If your selected item has a class name like "mi sel" then you have a menu system where you have different class names to help you style your menu. In that case the class "sel" would be your selected menu and the class name "bc" whould be any page that is in the currect breadcrumb hyerarchy. This menu system is pretty much deprecated but if that is what you have (you have not specified your dotnetnuke version and skin), then let me know, I have some old documentation somewhere...
2. If you don't see class names in such a way then your menu is generated by an xml parser and you should read this: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/DDRMenu-XSLT-templates and take a look at the 3 tutorials at the end of the article.